# Missing matching query when writing custom views

Tags: django, django-viewflow

Because of some form manipulations, I had to write custom views and followed the example in the cookbook. When writing in my view

```
if request.POST:
    if includeHelper.check_valid():
        process = includeHelper.save()

        request.activation.process = process
        request.activation.done()
        return redirect(get_next_task_url(request, request.activation.process))
```

I get a "Matching Query does not exist" error. I first thought my includeHelper, which is just a class managing formsets etc., returns a process that can not be saved due to some error in my code. However, when I skip the part that involves request.activation

```
if request.POST:
    if includeHelper.check_valid():
        process = includeHelper.save()
        return HttpResponse("ok")
```

it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `activation.process` and `activation.task` are instantiated in the `@flow_view` and `@flow_start_view` decorators

So you can't  just do `request.activation.process = process` to substitute the only process reference.

You can modify `request.activation.process` in place and call `activation.done()` at the end.